# <div id="main"> and <div id="content"> Main and Content are showing up blue and they need to be red?

Tags: html, program-entry-point

How do I make Main and content red? What am I doing wrong?  When I type this is in

```
<div id="main">
<div id="content">
```

main and content come out in blue and they should come out in red.
Thanks!

Comment: OMG, your code is invisible!!!!

Comment: `#main,#content { 
  color:red; // A request you,plz dont go blue
}`

Answer (score -1):

I can't see the code, except for the snippet you posted in a comment.

Question: Do you want the background or the textcolor to change?

Also you are using the selectors wrong. Just use an extra space between `#main,#content`.

Put this in your CSS file:

```css
#main, #content{color:red;}
```

I hope this helps!